# Toolkit wrappanle and rotation in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, silverlight-toolkit

when i rotate my phone , wrappanle is not changed and it does not get new figure . what should i do for that ?

[image]

and this is my xaml code :

```
       <ScrollViewer>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel>
            <Rectangle Height="100" Width="200" Fill="Red" />
            <Rectangle Margin="10" Height="100" Width="200" Fill="Red" />
            <Rectangle Height="100" Width="200" Fill="Red" />
            <Rectangle Height="100" Width="200" Fill="Red" Margin="10" />
            <Rectangle Height="100" Width="200" Fill="Red" />
            <Rectangle Height="100" Width="200" Fill="Red" Margin="10" />
            <Rectangle Height="100" Width="200" Fill="Red" />
            <Rectangle Height="100" Width="200" Fill="Red" Margin="10" />
            <Rectangle Height="100" Width="200" Fill="Red" />
            <Rectangle Height="100" Width="200" Fill="Red" Margin="10" />
            <Rectangle Height="100" Width="200" Fill="Red" />
            <Rectangle Height="100" Width="200" Fill="Red" Margin="10" />
            <Rectangle Height="100" Width="200" Fill="Red" />
            <Rectangle Height="100" Width="200" Fill="Red" Margin="10" />
            <Rectangle Height="100" Width="200" Fill="Red" />
            <Rectangle Height="100" Width="200" Fill="Red" Margin="10" />
        </toolkit:WrapPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `SupportedOrientations` property of your `PhoneApplicationPage` to `PortraitOrLandscape` value.

You can read more about screen orientation here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207002(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Orientations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207002%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Orientations)